# Magento 1.3.x Quick Search problem

Tags: magento, quick-search

We have built a website http://www.goshopping.pk/ (sorry had to post the link as its important for this question).

The quick search is not working as it should. For example, search "Nokia" and you will get all sorts of results. Search "Dell" and you get the same results. However, searching exact matches like "nokia 6600" or "Intel Core 2 DUO" or "Dell Inspiron" works perfectly fine.

We have rebuilt the search index, emptied the cache etc but it has no effect. What are we missing?

Help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what are your search settings

Comment: Minimal Query Length: 1
Maximum Query Length: 128
Maximum Query Words Count: 10
Search Type: Like (we also tried Fulltext but that has no effect)
Apply Layered Navigation if search results are less than: 2000

Answer (score 3):

One quick tip I normally advise people is to remove the description from quick search results in **Catalog > Manage Attributes > Attributes**

Obviously the description contains all sorts of words and can dilute search results. See if that improves anything.

Also in **Configuration > Catalog** I normally change the **Search Type** to *Fulltext* for more accurate results.

Comment: Well, we tried that but nothing. If you make a quick search on keyword "Nokia" you will see the first result shows up is a Laptop Bag Sleeve. This product contains no attributes except for "Model".

Comment: Thanks Adam. Based on your suggestion, we were able to resolve this. Here is what we did if anyone needs future reference:

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestion from Adam, we were able to resolve this. Here is what we did if anyone needs future reference:

1. We had about 400 attributes defined and a lot of them were set to search in quick search by our client. What we did is we manually ran a query via  phpmyadmin for table "eav_attribute" and updated ALL records to have is_searchable=0
2. We then manually edited the title and description record in eav_attribute table to is_searchable=1
3. Rebuilt the search index via Mage Admin and all was good.

Best,
K